# with or without 'return' in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I am solving a leetcode question. But I realized 'return' can make different output. The first code was accepted but the second one is not accepted.

```
function canJump(nums){
  let reachable = 0;
  
  for(let i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(reachable < i) return false;
    reachable = Math.max(reachable, i + nums[i]);
  }
  return true;
```

```
function canJump(nums){
  let reachable = 0;
  
  for(let i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(reachable < i) false;
    reachable = Math.max(reachable, i + nums[i]);
  }
  return true;
```

what is exactly the role of return in the javascript, and why does it make different output?

Comment: `return` stops the execution of a function and optionally *return*s a value - actually it always *return*s a value; but `return` === `return undefined` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: What is the expected behavior of `if(reachable < i) false;`? Why did you write it there? Are you trying to learn a programming language by guessing without a text book? That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`if(reachable < i) return false;`

Your function `canJump` returns `false` if your condition  `reachable < i` is `true`, meaning this code

`reachable = Math.max(reachable, i + nums[i]);`

does not get executed

Where in the second case

`if(reachable < i) false;`  you simple print `false` to the console or you are tying to I am assuming

Comment: `if(reachable < i) false;` doesn't print anything.

Comment: if my condition is true, it means the updating reachable value is running
`var canJump = function(nums) {
  let reachable = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(reachable < i){
      return false;
    } else {
      reachable = Math.max(reachable, i + nums[i]);  
    }
  }
  return true;
};`

cuz this looks like this actually